# Which computational models support bigotous programs?

Tags: computability, semantics, decidability

A [bigotous program](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Bigot) is a program which decides if its input is semantically equivalent to itself. Of course, this is impossible in a Turing complete language due to [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

In fact, its pretty hard to find any computational model that supports such a program. Indeed, even extending a computational model with the ability to write bigots often results in contradictions.

What are some computational models that *do* support bigots?

Comment: I think it would be useful to write down a formal definition. If $L_n$ is the language recognized by $n$-th program (under some reasonable coding), is a bigot a (code of a) program $b$ such that $L_b = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid L_b = L_n\}$?

Comment: What a definition, lol, +1

Comment: Even if you restrict to programs/functions computable within $\mathsf{NC}^1,$ as represented by the class of outputs of Barrington's transformation to 0/1-valued matrix branching programs (of a given program size and input size).. it's still interesting. No need to push all the way up to $\mathsf{P}$ to find a good question here.

Comment: (Or, perhaps, that's a decent, early observation: The description length of Barrington's branching programs are longer than their input length -- right?)

Comment: @DanielApon: What are you talking about? It seems like a legit definition to me, albeit a bit weird. Also, what do complexity classes have to do with anything here? Isn't this a question about (hyper)computation?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Not even standard hyper-computation has such programs.

Comment: How about infinite-time Turing machines?

Comment: Ahh-- I was thinking of restricting the computational model, rather than generalizing it (as the question appears to be about). Carry on~

Comment: @DanielApon I'm fine with either direction (ideally, an answer should address both).

Comment: @AndrejBauer maybe

Comment: There's a bit of a question what to do with programs that aren't total. That is, what is $L_n$ supposed to be when the $n$-th program diverges on some inputs?